# My function won't increase the value of it's input

Tags: javascript, function

I can't figure out why this won't give me a value of 1 for ducks. I've tried to do item += 1; return ++item; and a bunch of other stuff. Please help if you can. I'm new to coding so sorry if this is a stupid question.

```
let ducks = 0;
let currency = 10;

function runTransaction(item, cost) {
    if (currency >= cost) {
        currency -= cost;
        ++item;
    }
    else if (currency < cost) {
        return;
        alert("Insufficient Funds");
    }
}

runTransaction(ducks, 1);

alert(ducks);
```

Comment: It doesn't work because `item` isn't `ducks` but a copy of its value. Arguments in JS cannot be passed by reference.

Comment: @ikiK Incorrect.  `x -= y;` is the same as `x = x - y;`  See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Subtraction_assignment

Comment: Thank you @SimoneNigro for helping fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you @AngelPolitis for telling what was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You increment the function variable "item", not the value of "ducks". The solution is return the value of "item" and assign to "ducks".

```js
let ducks = 0;
let currency = 10;

function runTransaction(item, cost) {
    if (currency >= cost) {
        currency -= cost;
        ++item;
    }
    else if (currency < cost) {
        alert("Insufficient Funds");
    }
    return item; // return the value of "item"
}

ducks = runTransaction(ducks, 1); // Assign the value of "item" to "ducks"

alert(ducks);
```

Take a look to [JavaScript Function Scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because `item` is copy of `ducks`, not reference. Also "Insufficient Funds" alert will never work because it is after `return;` You can do this;

```
let ducks = 0;
let currency = 10;

function runTransaction(item, cost) {
    if (currency >= cost) {
        currency -= cost;
        ++item;
    }
    else if (currency < cost) {
        alert("Insufficient Funds");
    }
    return item;
}

ducks = runTransaction(ducks, 1);

alert(ducks);
```